# Reference Scala constructor args in default value

Tags: scala, constructor, arguments

In the following Scala code, the compiler is telling me `not found: value x` when I try to new up my default value for `y`, referencing `x`, another constructor argument.

```
class Foo(x: String, y: Bar = new Bar(x))

class Bar(a: String)
```

I trust there's good reason for this limitation. Can anyone shed some light and possibly offer an alternative approach?

Comment: Workaround: you could use different parameter groups like this: `class Foo(x: String)(y: Bar = new Bar(x))`.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative approach:

```
class Foo(x: String, y: Bar)

class Bar(a: String)

object Foo {
  def apply(x: String) = new Foo(x, new Bar(x))
}
```

Another one:

```
class Foo(x: String, y: Bar) {
  def this(x: String) = this(x, new Bar(x))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a class which has two members:

```
class Foo(x: String, y: Bar)
```

However when you bind `y` to a particular instance then effectively the class definition reduces to:

```
class Foo(x: String) { private val y = new Bar(x) }
```

Why? Since you are binding `y` to a `Bar(x)` instance, so no one should be able to change `y` without changing `x`.

Now if you notice the compiler is correct in saying `not found: value x` because `x` as an instance is only visible within constructor body. The same is true for `y`. Which means `new Bar(x)` in the following  code would be called before the constructor is actually called and `x` and `y` parameters are materialized:

```
class Foo(x: String, y: Bar = new Bar(x))
```

Comment: Interesting theory, but `class Foo(x: String)(y: Bar = new Bar(x))` works.

Comment: That is true because its a curried function. In this case x is already available for initialization of y.

Comment: It's not a curried function. It's just multiple parameter groups. Looks similar, but not the same.

Comment: Well I may not be aware of parameter groups or how they are different than curried parameters. Could you give some reference ?

Comment: "[Curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function" if a function of 1 parameter that returns another function of 1 parameter that returns... Parameter groups is just a special scala syntax for parameters of *method* or *constructor* (not *function*). Each group can hold more than 1 parameter. For method `def test(a: Int)(b: String)` you can't call `test(1)` and get a function.

Comment: I find no distinction between the way currying is done in method and function in Scala. Please check this: http://pastebin.com/k0UpXz11 I would appreciate if you can point to any Scala documentation that highlights this distinction.

Comment: There are no curried functions in your code sample, only parameter groups. Here is one: `val curr = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => a+b`. Usage: `val tenPlus = curr(10)`. Note the absence of `(_)`.