# Initialize Scala variables with Option

Tags: scala

I have this scala case class:

```
case class Foo
    (bar: String,
     original_bar: Option[String] = None)
```

I would like to set original_bar = bar by default (so original_bar always = Some(bar) by default) such as:

```
case class Foo
        (bar: String,
         original_bar: Option[String] = Some(bar))
```

But I get: not found: value bar, I also tried Some(Foo.bar) but no luck. Is there a way to set default value within case class or I have to set it when I initialise Foo object? Thanks

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508939/reference-scala-constructor-args-in-default-value

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can do that in the primary constructor. Here is an alternative:

```
case class Foo(bar: String, original_bar: Option[String])

object Foo {
  def apply(bar: String): Foo = new Foo(bar, Some(bar))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple parameter lists:

```
case class Foo(bar: String)(val original_bar: Option[String] = Some(bar))
```

This should work:

```
scala> case class Foo(bar: String)(val original_bar: Option[String] = Some(bar))
defined class Foo

scala> Foo("123")().original_bar
res79: Option[String] = Some(123)
```

This, however, interferes with case class functionality, for example, you won't be able to pattern match on second parameters list.

Comment: This doesn't work. I was thinking of the same thing myself: `Foo("Hello")(_)` returns `res1: Option[String] => Foo = <function1>`

Comment: You have to write `Foo("Hello")()`. Try it, it does work. I have checked it in REPL.

Answer (score 1):

Since, the `original_bar` is always going to be initialized using `bar`'s value, why not declare your case class as follows:

```
case class Foo(bar: String){
   val original_bar: Option[String] = Some(bar)
}
```

Also, if your `bar` is going to be changing, declare it as `var`:

```
case class Foo(var bar: String){
   val original_bar: Option[String] = Some(bar)
}
```

**EDIT**

This will do what you described in the comment:

Try this:

```
case class Foo(bar: String, original_bar: Option[String]) {
    def copy(bar1: String): Foo = Foo(bar1, this.original_bar)
}

val a = Foo("a",Some("a"))
a.bar // This gives 'a'
a.original_bar // This gives Some("a")

val b = a.copy("b")
b.bar // This gives 'b'
b.original_bar // This gives Some("a")
```

Comment: it would not be **always** initialized to `Some(bar)`. for example `Foo("bar", Some("baz"))`, at least it isn't that clear from op's question

Comment: But, that's not what the OP asked for? Or I'm just missing the point of the question?

Comment: I edited the question. I want the original_bar always = Some(bar). Currently, if I want to change bar, I use Foo.copy(bar = "new_bar"). I want to have a copy of the original bar so bar can be changed but I still know what is its original value is. I tested the code with val test1 = Foo(bar = "test1")  val test2 = test1.copy(bar = "test2"). test2.original_bar becomes test2 :( I want it to be test1

Comment: @Duc, see my last edit, it should do what you described in your last comment.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for you edit, I want to set original_bar by default based on bar value automatically when you set bar. If I have to set original_bar as well, Im back to square one :) this case class Foo
    (bar: String,
     original_bar: Option[String] = None) works fine if I have to init both bar and original_bar. Thanks

Comment: @Duc, I see, I think my answer and vptheron's answer cover all your needs, you only need to put the pieces together now.